# Struts 2 getText uses different language on controller and jsp

Tags: java, internationalization, struts2

I have an application that uses Struts 2 (and many other pieces), and the thing is that I get pages in 2 different languages. The pieces which I translate in the controller come in one language, and the ones that I translate on the jsp come in another one.

So in the controller I use

```
getText("something");
```

I get the result in Spanish, but in the jsp the pieces that use

I get in Catalan. I expected to get everything in Catalan.

So I have an interceptor that does:

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {

    final ActionContext context = invocation.getInvocationContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.get(HTTP_REQUEST);
    Map<String, Object> session = context.getSession();
    if(session.get(I18nInterceptor.DEFAULT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE) == null){
        Locale locale = chooseLocale(request.getLocale());
        session.put(I18nInterceptor.DEFAULT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE, locale);
        context.setLocale(locale);
    }
    return invocation.invoke();
}
```

This is based in the I18nIntereptor, and my function chooseLocale returns either Locale "es_ES" or "ca_ES".
If I do some debugging I can see that I have this values:

```
session.get(I18nInterceptor.DEFAULT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE) //ca_ES
request.getAttribute(I18nInterceptor.DEFAULT_PARAMETER) //ca_Es
request.getLocale() //ca
```

So I guess the problem is that the locale in the request is ca (and not ca_ES), which is not defined on my bundles and then falls back to the default (I guess). I alse see that Chrome has on it's headers

```
Accept-Language:ca,es;q=0.8
```

So is there any way that I can change the request locale to either ca_ES or es_ES?

Comment: I'm kind of confused.  You say that there is NO catalan bundle, but you also say that in the JSP it does resolve Catalan text.  How is this possible?  What do you mean by "in the JSP" -- you are using the <s:text>?

Comment: Sorry about that, I explained it really bad. My bundle is defined as "ca_ES", but the request comes just as "ca".